# Lua filter for pandoc to append html

Tags: html, lua, markdown, pandoc

I'm currently compiling markdown to html using pandoc:

```
    pandoc in.md -o out.html
```

and would like to include the same piece of html code in each of the output files, without having to write it into my markdown file.

I was hoping that a lua filter would do the job. However, the docs seem to indicate the filters will only respond to a sequence of characters within my markdown file, rather than appending something to each file.

I've played around with CSS (I've never used it before), but it doesn't look like I can just add arbitrary html code like this (correct me if I'm wrong).

To summarize, I'd like to find a way to add html code to my output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lua filter is likely to be overkill here. Pandoc has an option [`--include-after-body`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--include-after-body) (or `--include-before-body`) which will do what you need:

> `-A FILE`, `--include-after-body=FILE|URL`
>
> Include contents of FILE, verbatim, at the end of the document body (before the `</body>` tag in HTML, or the `\end{document}` command in LaTeX). This option can be used repeatedly to include multiple files. They will be included in the order specified. Implies `--standalone`.